# Loops and ggplots and columns of dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I have a list of the column names in a dataframe called columns using colnames().
I am looping through the list with a counter, i, and creating a ggplot for each one. The trouble I am running into is in
`ggplot(aes(x = something, y = columns[i]))`

Since columns[i] is a string it just makes a plot with the y axis called the column I actually wanted to select but with no values. How can I select the column without it being a string. I have tried `noquote()` and `as.name()` but that seems to change them to incompatible types.

Comment: Have a look at `?aes_string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @Markus, you can look at `aes_string`, here is an example using quoted strings

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x="hp", y="mpg" ))+geom_point()
```

Answer (score 2):

We can convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(ggplot2)
columns <- c("mpg", "wt")
plist <- lapply(columns, function(nm) 
       ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, !! rlang::sym(nm))) +
         geom_col()

)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = something, y = df[,columns[i]]))
```